# Globally matching and replacing multi-line text

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I am working on a project with many files (100+).

I have two FE properties on every page that I'd like to update. For example,

```
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropTwo"
                },
```

I could grep for "PropOne" and "Prop2" individually, but I'd rather match on  the entire property object for more accuracy.

Is there a way to find and update the values using something like GREP?

Edit: Expected output would be:

```
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropTwo"
                },
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I would like to end up with property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is the new PropOne "
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is the new PropTwo"
                },

Comment: Not in comments, update the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat old
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropTwo"
                },

$ cat new
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropTwo"
                },
```

.

```
$ cat file
lines before
the target
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "PropTwo"
                },
lines after
the target

$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '
    ARGIND==1 { old=$0; next }
    ARGIND==2 { new=$0; next }
    s=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' old new file
lines before
the target
                property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    value: "this is new PropTwo"
                },
lines after
the target
$
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and ARGIND. A POSIX version isn't hard to come up with if necessary. It uses string comparison and replacement so regexp and/or backreference metacharacters in your files will be treated as literals and so do not need any special consideration (unlike, say, if you were to attempt to use sed or any other regexp-based approach).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `gnu awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS='},' 'NF {
   sub(/value: "[^"]*"/, "\"this is new " ($1=="property1:"?"PropOne":"PropTwo") "\"")
}
{
   ORS=RT
} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
               property1: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    "this is new PropOne"
                },
                property2: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true,
                    "this is new PropTwo"
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^\s*property.*: {/,/^\s*},/s/"\(.*\)"/"this is the new &"/' file
```

This matches on a range of lines starting with `property` and ending with `},` and then substitute the string between double quotes with the required replacement (using a back reference if needed).